# How to compile a xul extension in Ubuntu 13.04 ? (specifically xul-ext-gnome-keyring)

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, keyrings, xulrunner

I am using the [**gnome-keyring extension**](https://github.com/infinity0/mozilla-gnome-keyring) for Firefox/Thunderbird.

There used to be a [PPA](http://ppa.launchpad.net/fat-lobyte9/ppa-public/ubuntu) for this plugin, but the **maintainer gave up**, as the new policy for xulrunner makes it uneasy to keep up with latest firefox version: see the rationale [here](https://github.com/infinity0/mozilla-gnome-keyring/issues/26).
It refers specifically to [this post](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-motu/2011-May/007088.html) stating xulrunner dev will be removed from Ubuntu.

So the extension is now available in Debian, in Fedora, but not in Ubuntu !

Currently, I just pinned Firefox to the latest compatible version (22), but I am willing to compile this extension by hand.
The source code can be found [on github](https://github.com/infinity0/mozilla-gnome-keyring). It depends on xulrunner sdk.

So here is my questions:

- is there a way to get xulrunner sdk into my system and to compile this extension ?
- if so, is it likely to work with Firefox/Thunderbird as shipped by Ubuntu ?
- is there some kind of howto / documentation on the current state of developping / maintaining / packaging extensions for Firefox on Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could compile using the following method:

1. download xulrunner-sdk from http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/, chooising the version corresponding to the target version of Firefox (eg. 24.0 for latest FF version as of 2013-09-18)
2. install firefox-dev and gnome-keyring-dev packages
3. unpack xulrunner-sdk
4. compile with:

   XUL_CFLAGS="-I../../xulrunner-sdk/include -I../../xulrunner-sdk/include/nspr" XUL_LDFLAGS="-L../../xulrunner-sdk/lib -lxpcomglue_s -lxul -lmozalloc -lplds4 -lplc4 -lnspr4 -lpthread -ldl" XPCOM_ABI_FLAGS="-Wl,-rpath=/usr/lib/firefox" make
5. install extension with the xpi file produced

Answer (score 0):

There are some resources around how to package a Firefox extension:

- [HowTo package and publish Firefox extensions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MozillaTeam/Extensions/Packaging)
- [A HowTo 'Log' from a Dev Week](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MeetingLogs/devweek0802/FFExtensions)
- [Manual for mozilla-devscripts](http://dev.man-online.org/package/main/mozilla-devscripts/)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to gather this information! Not exactly an answer to my question, but far better than nothing. Will wait a bit more for other answers to come, and accept your answer if nothing more specific comes.